# Verifying if a polynomial is reducible via congruences

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I want to prove or disprove whether the polynomial $f(x) = x^4 + 3x^3 + 3x^2 -5$ is reducible over $\mathbb Z$.

What I have so far is that $3x^3+3x^2-3\equiv_3 0$, so $$x^4 + 3x^3 + 3x^2 - 5 \equiv_3 x^4 -2$$
Since both polynomials are congruent modulo $3$, it should be easier to work with $g(x) = x^4-2$. In modulo $3$ there are three unique possibilities, \begin{align*}x^4 - 2 &\equiv_3 0, 1, 2 \\ \implies x^4 &\equiv_3 2, 3, 4 \\ \implies x^4 &\equiv_3 0, 1, 2\end{align*}
But this is where I'm not sure how to continue. I suspect $f$ is not reducible over the integers.

Answer (score 1):

Being irreducible modulo $p$ for some prime $p$ implies irreducibility over $\mathbf Z$, but choosing $p = 3$ isn't good: $x^4 - 2 \equiv (x^2+x+2)(x^2+2x+2) \bmod 3$. Try reducing modulo another prime.

Have you learned how to prove irreducibility sometimes if a polynomial is reducible modulo two different primes in incompatible ways (that is, incompatible with being reducible over $\mathbf Z$)?

Comment: So far the only modulo prime I can come up with is $p=2$, where $x^4+3x^3+3x^2-5\equiv_2 x^4 + x^3 + x^2 - 5 \equiv _2 0, 1$

Comment: What does it mean that you can only "come up with" the prime 2?  There are lots of prime numbers.  The choice $p=2$ is bad since it is reducible mod 2 (with factor $x-1$).

Answer (score 1):

You could check that your polynomial is [irreducible](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Factor%5Bx%5E4%20%2B%203x%5E3%20%2B%203x%5E2%20-5%2C%20Mod-%3E7%5D) $\mod 7$, so also irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Alternatively, as @KCd suggested, try factoring it $\mod 2$ and $\mod 3$. $\mod 2$ it factors into factors of degree $1$ and $3$, while $\mod 3$ it factors into factors of degree $2$, $2$.  That implies it does not factor over $\mathbb{Z}$.